# converting nsMutablestring to nsdata in ios

Tags: ios, nsdata

I'm new to the iOS development I'm trying to convert the append in NSdata but I'm unable to do that conversion I have tried some codes. In my Nsmutable String I have a url link which have the video I'm passing the string form json  so now I want to append with the NSdata to display that video url

this is code for the NSmutablesring which pass the url link

```
-(void)setDataSource:(vedios *)inVideosObj
{

    self.titile.text = inVideosObj.title;

    url =[NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

}
```

NSMutablestring appeand coding:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{

    NSData *mydata =[self.responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];

    [self.responseData appendString:data];



}
```

Comment: you want NSData to NSMutableString or NSMutableString  to NSData

Comment: NSMutableString to NSData @iDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising responseData as a NSMutableString. Initialise it as a NSMutableData

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableData * responseData;
```

now in

```
-(void)setDataSource:(vedios *)inVideosObj
{
    //Your work
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
    [self.responseData appendData: data];

}
```

then convert this `self.responseData` to `NSString` if you want..

```
NSString * responseString = [NSString alloc] initWithData: self.responseData encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding]
```

Enjoy..!!

Comment: thanks for ur help it worked but i have another problem. now when im passing the self.responsedata to the movieplayer converting into string its showing data: null error in console how to resolve this @iProgrammer

Comment: Whats the another problem?

Comment: now when im passing the self.responsedata to the movieplayer converting into string its showing data: null error in console how to resolve this @iProgrammer

Comment: Check when you are converting your data into string self.response is not null. Apply NSLog (@"Data : %@", self.responseData). And After converting to String print your string. How are you passing your self.responseData to MoviePlayer.

Comment: pls  check this link i have posted that problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324688/getting-data-null-in-the-convertion-of-msmutabledata-to-string-in-ios/21324974?noredirect=1#21324974

Answer (score 3):

NSString to NSData

```
NSString* strResult = @"yourstring";
NSData* dataResult = [strResult dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

NSData to NSMutableString

```
NSMutableString *jsonStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonStr);
```